# How to open a table from ODBC 32bit source in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, bigdata

When i open a table with 60M+ rows, MS Access throw an error. After few minutes awaiting (about 10) it show me dialog: "Can't execute query. Query result bigger than 2Gb or disk memory low".

Is there a way to open its huge table from 32 ODBC (not 64!) source with MS Access?

Is there a pagination or view only first 10(100, 1000, etc.) records of table?

Comment: So, MS Access can export huge table to text file or another format, but is a way to view directly in access?

Comment: ".. a way to view 60M+ rows directly .." - would love if you could visualize to us how that should be possible.

Comment: Access starts slowing down, at about 500K networked records, and 150mb file size - can't imagine trying to push the M$ stated limit, of 2gb. We use ODBC with our iSeries and Access, but are very careful, to only query what we need, and it works just fine.